How to install LightGBM CUDA with python-poetry?
According to the documentation on PyPi, to install LightGBM with CUDA support we should use the command
pip install lightgbm --config-settings=cmake.define.USE_CUDA=ON

I'm currently working on a project which uses Poetry for dependency management. I would like to add LightGBM with CUDA support to the project. Installing LightGBM would pip as above would work, however in this case this particular dependency, LightGBM, would not be managed by Poetry. So, the question is
Is there a Poetry equivalent to the above pip command? More generally, is there a way to install LightGBM CUDA with Poetry?
I searched online and found some workarounds, like opening the poetry virtual environment and installing LightGBM with pip as in the above pip command. However, I would like the LightGBM version to be managed by Poetry like all the other packages.
